# Insert Into stored procedure not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to insert into a table using a stored procedure. The executed stored produce results in zero (0). I guess which means the stored procedure is successful.

But when I look at the table, the record is not added. How can I fix it?

**SQL**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE displayToDO
    @ID int =2,
    @Title varchar(50),
    @Description varchar(255),
    @Date date,
    @Time time,
    @Location varchar(50),
    @Priority varchar(20),
    @NotificationType varchar(30)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO toDOLIST(ID, Title, Description, Date, Time, Location, Priority, NotificationTYPE)
    VALUES (@Title, @Description, @Date, @Time, @Location, @Priority, @NotificationType)
END
```

Asp.net:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <div class="insertData">
        <asp:Label ID="title" runat="server" Text="Title"></asp:Label> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="titleBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />

        <asp:Label ID="description" runat="server" Text="Description"></asp:Label>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="descriptionBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />

        <asp:Label ID="dateLabel" runat="server" Text="Date"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Calendar ID="date" runat="server"></asp:Calendar><br />

        <asp:Label ID="time" runat="server" Text="Time"></asp:Label>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="timeBoxHr" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp; <asp:TextBox ID="timeBoxMin" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />

        <asp:Label ID="location" runat="server" Text="Location"></asp:Label>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="locationBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />

        <asp:Label ID="priority" runat="server" Text="Priority"></asp:Label>    
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;    
        <asp:DropDownList ID="priorityDrop" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem>-</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="notification" runat="server" Text="Notification Type"></asp:Label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;   
        <asp:DropDownList ID="notificationDrop" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem>12 hrs before</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>1 day Before</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>3 Day before</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>A Week before</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>

    </div>
   <br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Insert" onclick="Button2_Click" />
    <br /><br /><br /><br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Display" />
    <br /><br /><br /><br />
     <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
        onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
</form>
```

C#:

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String time = timeBoxHr.Text + ":" + timeBoxMin.Text + ":00";  
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationString))
        {

            SqlCommand scommand = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
            scommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            scommand.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = titleBox.Text;
            scommand.Parameters.Add("@Title", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = titleBox.Text;
            scommand.Parameters.Add("@Description", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = descriptionBox.Text;
            scommand.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.Date).Value = date.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString();
            scommand.Parameters.Add("@Time", SqlDbType.Time).Value = time;
            scommand.Parameters.Add("@Location", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = locationBox.Text;
            scommand.Parameters.Add("@Priority", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = priorityDrop.Text;
            scommand.Parameters.Add("@NotificationType", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30).Value = notificationDrop.Text;
            try
            {
                if (scommand.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    scommand.Connection.Open();
                }
                scommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
            finally
            {
                scommand.Connection.Close();
            }
       }
```

Comment: I see very professional exception handling `catch (Exception) { }`...  also why this question has java, android tags?

Comment: Why did you tag this java and android if you are using ASP.net and C#? I have changed the tags

Comment: Also seems like we have a serial upvoter here... Bad, bad Adarash...

Comment: How do you know the result is zero? I don't see you adding a parameter for return value. Are you confusing the result of `ExecuteNonQuery` which is rows affected, not return value?

Comment: @Selvin I was about to ask a Android question first and then replaced the content to ask this question. I forgot to change the tags